# find duplicate objects within a list of lists (using linq?)

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list of lists that I created with LINQ to contain a status code object:

```
List<List<StatusLookup>> statusList = new List<List<StatusLookup>>();

foreach(var action in DbmsReport.Actions){
    statusList.Add((from stat in MyFactory.CreateQueryable<StatusLookup>()
                    where stat.ActionTypes.Contains(action)
                    select stat).ToList());
}
```

I now need to somehow parse this `statusList` and find all of the StatusLookup objects that are in each list of lists, so for example:

```
DbmsReport.Actions = ( sprint, fight );

StatusLookup = ( { id = 0, text = "exhausted", ActionTypes = ( sprint, fight ) }
                 { id = 1, text = "tired", ActionTypes = ( jog, sprint, fight ) }
                 { id = 2, text = "rested", ActionTypes = ( sleep ) }
               );
```

So in this case I'd need to get a list that contains `StatusLookup` for "exhausted" and "tired" in no particular order, what is the best way to get this list? As can be seen in this example, there can be either 1 or more than 1 `StatusLookup` for each `DbmsReport`

Comment: Do you have to keep them as lists-of-lists? what if you flattened it out to one big list? Easy query then

Comment: No I do not have to keep it as a list of lists, please provide an example of this flattened out list

Comment: If `DbmsReport.Actions = (spring,fight)` do you want all StatusLookup where ActionTypes contain sprint *and* fight or where ActionTypes contains sprint *OR* fight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just do?

```
var lookups= MyFactory.CreateQueryable<StatusLookup>()
             .Where(x=> DbmsReport.Actions.All(y=>x.ActionTypes.Contains(y))).ToList();
```

or if you want an or condition (ie Report= sprint,fight and you want to find all Lookups that have either sprint or fight) then

```
var lookups= MyFactory.CreateQueryable<StatusLookup>()
             .Where(x=> DbmsReport.Actions.Any(y=>x.ActionTypes.Contains(y))).ToList();
```

Comment: Perfect, the first example is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is when I try the above I get a "Specified method is not supported." NotSupportedException This might have something to do with MyFactory being an Nhibernate factory...

Comment: So this did end up working, I just had to separate the `MyFactory.CreateQueryable<StatusLookup>()` to its own variable first, ie `var allStatuses = MyFactory.CreateQueryable<StatusLookup>().ToList()` then replace the `MyFactory.Crea.....` in our example with `allStatuses`

Answer (score 1):

Try this to flatten it out, additionally you can add where clauses as necessary.

```
var r = from p in statusList
        from q in p
        select q;
```